# How to search for rows that are a substring of a value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a full length item code that I am looking for, `'34FDE353UE2'` and a table full of a shortened version of said item codes, like this

```
itemCode
============
34FDE
35DCF
34FPE
....
```

How can I look through my rows to see if any of them match the `'34FDE353UE2'`?  In my example, I would hope to get back the first row since `34FDE` is a substring of `'34FDE353UE2'`.  How can I write a query to do this?

Using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: `JOIN` using `LIKE` in its `ON` condition

Comment: Is 53UE2 a substring of 34FDE353UE2?

Comment: if i could downvote comments i would @SuperMario w3schools had a history with incorrect/incomplete documentation  and or outdated and unsafe programming tutorials in the past

Answer (score 5):

With `like`:

```
select * from tablename
where '34FDE353UE2' like concat(itemCode, '%')
```

this will return rows where itemCode's value is the starting chars of `'34FDE353UE2'`. 
If you want rows where `itemcode` is a substring of `'34FDE353UE2'` then:

```
select * from tablename
where '34FDE353UE2' like concat('%', itemCode, '%')
```

Comment: That was the easiest way.  Thank you.  I'd give you the solution but turns out my question was a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select * from tablename where  REGEXP_SUBSTR(itemCode,'34FDE353UE2')
```

Comment: Ideally you should not use the regex engine for something which can be done without with simple string matching functions.

Comment: @RaymondNijland i am not ideal i am a human being!!! :-)

Comment: @RaymondNijland i know the simple ones!!! :-)

Comment: indeed very true that also means your smarter then a machine the optimizer does not know or does not care to replace `REGEXP_SUBSTR(itemCode,'34FDE353UE2')` with a simple string matching function,,

Comment: Can you **explaim** why that will work? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer